# How do avoid context menu in opensuse to open on mousepress

Tags: gnome, eclipse, opensuse, context-menu, right-click

I am using opensuse 12.1 via a virtual maschine. I'm using Gnome 3.2.1 and having this annoying problem, that whenever I want to open the context menu with the right mouse button it opens directly when I press the button.

On Windows and Ubuntu the behavior is, that the menu opens after I release the button again.

The annoying thing is, that when I click the right mouse button (press and release directly) opensuse selects the entry lying in the menu under the mouse pointer. That leads to really severe problems.

Also I see, that the problem is not in every program. Especially in Eclipse the program occurs. But not only in Eclipse.

Has somebody an idea about how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing default theme/window manager.